# I am trying to plot following data in Google Data Studio, but I am unable to

Tags: looker-studio

[Link for the data to be plotted in excel format](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSorsC__e2rH1RF_pdpe7vjYWu1SXvbz48LpLkhldoc/edit?usp=sharing)

You can access the data from the above link. Basically I am able to plot the above data in excel. But I want to plot them in Data studio. And when I tried I am able to get only this

[image]

As you can see, it's nowhere called data visualization and I am suspecting the highlighted average metric of temperature. I want it to be "auto". But there is no option for that

I want something similar to this for each minute

[image]

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa Now Google Data studio has support for every minute as well. Can you please help me with this new method in my above question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your ts filed is formatted as "Date Hour minute"  and in the style section you've set Missing Data to "Linear interpolation" which essentially joins the dots where you have no data for that minute.

[image]